# How to read config file not commited to git

Tags: javascript, git, passwords, config

Suppose I have a website that needs to read an api key from a config file.

In the `index.html`, I can add `<script src="js/config.js"></script>` at the very bottom, and so it will import the `config.js` inside.

Suppose inside the `config.js`, I have the following:
`var config_obj = {"pwd":"demo"};`

Now I **don't** want this file to be committed to GitHub, but I **still want to be able to read the config_obj**. How do I do this?

If I add in `js/config.js` in my `.gitignore` it still does not work. I want to be able to still get access to this object, but since the file is not commmitted, I get the error `Uncaught ReferenceError: config_obj is not defined`

What is the proper way to do this?

Comment: `I don't want this file to be committed to GitHub, but I still want to be able to read the config_obj. How do I do this?` - I even surprise if I could eat rice without having it in my place. Probably, you want to check before using it? `if(config_obj){`

Comment: If the variable isn't in your git repo, how do you expect it to exist?

Comment: I am wondering on how to do this. I don't want to commit the config.js because then anyone can see my API key. It makes total sense as why I get the error, but I want to know if there is a way to over come this without putting in the config file and exposing data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the API key is private, and you do not want to expose it to user using your website, you should never put it into your websites javascipt, as they will be run on the users browser. If you need to communicate with a remote server requiring a private API-key, you will need somekind of a backend encapsulating that communication.

However if the website will be private or the API-key is not a secret (and you just don't want to put it into version control), I would copy the `config.js` manually to the server.

Comment: Good answer. But I don't think it satisfies the question.

Comment: This is a website hosted by github

Comment: @KSplitX In a public Github repository you cannot hide a secret.